# How can I plot a crosstable of summary data

Tags: r

I´m summarizing a set of helpdesk tickets using R tapply with summary. How could I  plot a crosstable of this data to show a five-number-summary of each category?

```
tsSummary = tapply(tickets$timeSpent, tickets$category, summary)

$ERROR
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    1.16   16.26   81.51   61.68  578.40 

$SUPPORT
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    3.28   24.19   93.02   93.38 2328.00 

$DEFECT
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    3.71   28.16  134.20  148.90 2572.00 

$SYSTEM
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    5.33   22.45   95.31   64.61 1178.00 

$OTHERS
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    1.99   22.17  102.60  115.60 3461.00
```

I would like to plot (as image ) something like this:

```
          Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
$ERROR    0.00    1.16   16.26   81.51   61.68  578.40 
$SUPPORT  0.00    3.28   24.19   93.02   93.38 2328.00 
$DEFECT   0.00    3.71   28.16  134.20  148.90 2572.00 
$SYSTEM   0.00    5.33   22.45   95.31   64.61 1178.00 
$OTHERS   0.00    1.99   22.17  102.60  115.60 3461.00
```

Any help?

Comment: What do you mean by plot? Do you want to show the printed numbers or do you want to visually represent them (e.g., as boxplots)?

Comment: v1<-summary(error), v2<-summary(support) etc and then table<-rbind(v1,v2) may do it.

Comment: @epc or do you literally want to plot a table, as discussed on [RBloggers](http://www.r-bloggers.com/visualizing-tables-with-plot-table/) ?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the answers. What I meant is that I really would to have the table draw in a png or pdf as table (not boxplot) with a header for the min, 1q, median, mean, 3q and max on each row the summary name followed by the respective values.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is collapse your list of tables into one, you can use `do.call`. Here's an example similar to your using the `iris` dataset:

```
tsSummary <- tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, summary)
do.call(rbind, tsSummary)
##            Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu. Max.
## setosa      4.3   4.800    5.0 5.006     5.2  5.8
## versicolor  4.9   5.600    5.9 5.936     6.3  7.0
## virginica   4.9   6.225    6.5 6.588     6.9  7.9
```

If you want to visualize this. You probably want a `boxplot`:

```
boxplot(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
```

[image]